# Applying Inversed Rules

Tags: rule

If I have

```
{x->2,y->3,z->19}
```

and make many calculations
and finaly get

```
First/@FactorInteger[57]
```

> {3, 19}

how can I apply the inversed rules to get

> {y,z}

without using

```
/.{2->x,3->y,19->z}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't `{3, 19} /. Map[Reverse, {x -> 2, y -> 3, z -> 19}]` work?

Comment: it worked!thanks

Comment: @Jenny_mathy You can also write `Reverse[rules, {2}]`

Comment: If rules are at level 2, one may also use the shorter `Reverse/@ruleList`